# How to set min number of lines to 2 in a div

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[image: cards]

So i can't get all the cards to be the same height, the reason this is happening is that main title is sometimes 2 or 1 lines (i have handled the image height case). What would be the best way to solve this? I have have tried using min-height but it leaves too much room in the bottom of the 1 line cases. I am using angular material library in my angular project.

component html

```
     <mat-card class="example-card " >
    <mat-card-header  >
      <mat-card-title class="hres">{{ product.name }}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle> {{ product.type | titlecase   }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>

    <div >
      <img *ngIf="product.type=='video'" class="imh"  mat-card-image src="../../assets/images/Products/Videos/{{product.image.imageSrc[0]}}" >

      <div>
        <img *ngIf="product.type=='book'" class="imh"  mat-card-image  src="../../assets/images/Products/Books/{{product.image.imageSrc[0]}}" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <mat-card-content>
      <button mat-button>PRICE</button>
      <p style="display: inline;">$ {{ product.price }}</p>
      <button mat-raised-button style="float: right;" *ngIf="!isAdmin" color="primary">Add to cart</button>
    </mat-card-content>
    <!-- <mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card-actions> -->
  </mat-card>
```

component css

```
  h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    flex: 1;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .tools {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .mC{
    cursor: pointer;

  }
  .cardH{
  }
  .imh{
    /* overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;

     */
    object-fit:scale-down;
    max-height: 25vh;
    min-height: 25vh;
    /* object-position: top; */
  }
  .hres{

    /* max-height: 5vh; */
    /* min-height: 5.5vh; */
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
```

This is more a single card, the image just shows all the cards (looped from a array) in a grid.

Comment: If you fix the height of the example card instead of letting it dynamically change if your content height changes, your image needs to be positioned accordingly. If you know that the title is the only thing that changes the height dynamically, fix its height. Do it for the elements that can change height dynamically inside the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit number of lines/character to be showed in the title...this way no matter how long the title is it will get truncated and will show in one line only.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(
      farthest-side at bottom left,
      rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5), 
      #246756
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      farthest-corner at bottom right,
      rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.5), 
      #246756 400px
    );
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #246756;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="box">
  Hey, don't cut me off like that. I want to speak my mind and don't appreciate being put into a box.
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that the min-height solution would be the best option. If it looks like there's way too much space you could move the `product.type` somewhere else. Good luck.

Comment: Please present a code snippet to help others understand how this addresses the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css align-items: stretch

like this little example:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: #f00;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
    
    .box {
        width: 200px;   
        background-color: #0f0;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .small {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    .large {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="large"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="small"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="large"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after that you can take a look at css flex-wrap to continue in the next line